# cannot convert array with text index to object

Tags: javascript

I have a object that is supposed to display only one text box with the value "newtext" in it. I figured that by passing an object as the parameter for the object constructor (function name y) that I can inject a 1 into a text box. How can I add text this way?

In the future I'll have multiple text boxes and I want to populate them with values based on values from an external array being fed into the constructor.

```
<div ID='x'></div>
<script>
function y(imp){
  this.t=[];
  this.f=document.createElement('FORM');
  this.t['text']=document.createElement('INPUT');
  document.getElementById('x').appendChild(this.f);
  this.f.appendChild(this.t['text']);
  this.t['text'].value=imp['text'].value; //tried overriding the textbox value with value from inbound parameters.
}
var add=[];
add['text'].value='newtext'; // Tried to set textbox value here but failed
var z=new y(add);
</script>
```

Comment: What is imp? If I try this function changing imp with a text value it works.

Comment: imp is the array of values for multiple text boxes. I only showed one here but eventually I want to add another box and set values for both at once with an array of values

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost right. The problem is that the add array is not initialized, so add['text'] is not a textbox but an empty value.
For this to work you have to either initialize add['text'] to be a INPUT field or set there the text value

```
<div ID='x'></div>
<script>
function y(imp){
  this.t=[];
  this.f=document.createElement('FORM');
  this.t['text']=document.createElement('INPUT');
  document.getElementById('x').appendChild(this.f);
  this.f.appendChild(this.t['text']);
  this.t['text'].value=imp['text']; //tried overriding the textbox value with value from inbound parameters.
}
var add=[];
add['text']='newtext'; // Tried to set textbox value here but failed
var z=new y(add);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. I had to make an object containing the "value" parameter. This code:

```
function val(v){this.value=v}
var arr=[];
arr['width']=new val(64);
```

will set arr['width'].value to be 64.

Comment: There is no need to create objects when all you want is the string

Comment: my object will be getting more complicated than this. But I think I'm able to continue my project now. Thanks for all help.